# No cocoapod command responding

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to update my pods, using `pod update`, but what I found after it didn't respond is no cocoa-pod command is working, whether I try '`outdated`' or '`install`' etc.

I have updated ruby, re-installed cocoa pods twice. Verbose gives no output, I suspect it's getting stuck somewhere.

I have tried

```
pod update 
pod outdated --verbose
```

In each case it didn't give any output on console, also when I tried updating it deleted the supporting files and broke the build.

Please help.

Here is my bash_profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

**** update *****
I have also tried creating new project and setting up cocoa pods but no avail.

Comment: Did you delete de pod lock file (Podfile.lock) before trying install ?

Comment: Also, posting your bashprofile(s) may help us find the reason.

Comment: @user3344236 deleting lock file doesn't seems to be working

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan added the bash profile

Comment: From what is listed, I might assume that it's either an issue of podfile.lock or the RVM scripts (in case those have been modified manually). The strange thing is that there's no output on the console, which makes me think that the output has been forwarded to a file. Might that be the case?

Comment: I haven't modified any script ever and I have downloaded RVM fresh to update ruby to latest version and before that I had same issue , also tried deleting lock file but had same trouble

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally go this working what i did was following

1. sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
2. gem install cocoapods
3. pod repo remove master
4. pod setup

And everything got sorted out.